# Gradle 0.9.2 with Appengine 1.4.2

Tags: google-app-engine, plugins, gradle

Is there a **Gradle plugin** (compatible with Gradle 0.9.2) that'll let me deploy to **Google App Engine** 1.4.2?

If yes, how can I integrate it (build.gradle snippet)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Axel,

today is your lucky day. ;-) I just released a [Gradle GAE plugin](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-gae-plugin) that provides tasks for uploading, running and managing Google App Engine Java projects. Give it a shot. The 
documentation describes setup and convention properties in detail. Let me know if you have feedback or feature requests.

Comment: Hey Benjamin! We are having great results so far! How can I store a password to run gaeUpload from Jenkins (without ever having to input it from the command-line)?

Comment: Awesome! Good to hear. Internally the plugin uses [appcfg.sh](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/uploadinganapp.html) (actually the Java implementation of it) which doesn't provide a way to store the password per se as far as I can see. I asked [this question](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java/browse_thread/thread/84c0983be6d62565#) on the Google App Engine Java forum. If you know a way to do that please let me know so I can build it in. Right now there's no support for it.

Comment: I "solved" this by running the build once from a shell within the workspace and entering the password by hand.

Comment: Yeah, once you enter it correctly the sign-in credentials get stored as a cookie.

Comment: I now face another issue: how can I execute gaeRun and have it NOT wait? So I can run an HtmlUnit test against the app, and stop the server afterwards.

Comment: That feature doesn't exist yet. Can you open an issue on GitHub? I'll try to working on this as soon as I can.

Comment: The issues have been logged. Did you make any progress?

Comment: I implemented passing in the password. Running the local development server in the background hasn't been implemented yet. I wanted to release both fixes at once. Let me know if the password passin feature is important enough to create a subrelease.

Comment: Yes, that would definitely be great.

Comment: I'd like you to give it a shot before I officially release it. Can you send me a mail? I'd send you the new version then.

Comment: @Axel: Version 0.3 of the plugin has been released. Both requested features are part of this release.

Answer (score 1):

The Spring Security build uses gradle to deploy a sample app to GAE. You could copy that (see the [sample app gradle file](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/samples/gae-xml/gae.gradle)), or clone the repo and use it in place as a guide. It uses a simple [internal plugin](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/buildSrc/src/main/groovy/gae/GaePlugin.groovy).